# Installed version throw exception "the system cannot find the file specified" exe runs fine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I've created a app with an help menu.

The help's callback function should open a Word file.

I've attached the file `User's Manual v2.docx` to the project (set it to Embedded resource) and it works when I run it from VS and when I run it from the exe it self. But when I install the app and run the installed exe the help call back function throws an exception:

> the system cannot find the file specified

```
private void manualToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Process.Start("User's Manual v2.docx");
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong and/or how to make it work?

Comment: The file may not be installed at the same location (the one shown seems incomplete), or the user may not have Word installed?

Comment: The file must exist on disk for this to work, either ship the doc as an external file or output it to disk from your exe (via GetManifestResourceStream and a StreamWriter)

Comment: A relative path is relative to the *working directory* not to the directory your application is in. Specify an absolute path by combining the path to your executable with the relative path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not using the resource file, it's finding the file you embedded. Take it out as a resource and add the file to your project. Make sure you set copy always, or copy if newer against the word file.

If you want to embed it so you don't have to have it as an extra file. You'd need to extract it from the resource, save it as a (temporary?) file and then call Process.Start for that.